# How can I allow 12pt font in the ACM LaTeX sample?

Tags: templates

We're using the [ACM SIG Proceedings Template](http://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template) for our report on our final project. However, our professor has allowed us to use 12pt font rather than 11pt for the final writeup.

I'm completely new to LaTeX templates... and this one looks pretty complex. My question is, how can I enable 12pt font for the substance of our paper without completely ruining the format of everything else (headers, tables, etc)? Is it possible to change the font type as well?

Comment: It is likely that the class supports using`\documentclass[12pt]{sig-alternate}`. I would try this first. If it doesn't work then you'll have to work harder:)

Comment: That is the culprit of templates, some try to be generic others try to be as fixed (converning the layout) as possible, leaving the starter utterly confused.

Comment: The `sig-alternate` class is ***very*** rigid; it still uses `\newfont` declarations, making it one of the worst examples of document class I know. Nobody should use it, unless forced by submission rules.

Comment: You can add a single line like `\Huge` or `\LARGE` after `\begin{document}`. This will affect the size of everything that follows.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the news isn't encouraging. The class file `sig-alternate-05-2015.cls` contains the following code, starting at about line 130:

```
\newcount\ACM@basesize
\ACM@basesize=9\relax
\DeclareOption{9pt}{\ACM@basesize=9\relax}
\DeclareOption{10pt}{\ACM@basesize=10\relax}
\DeclareOption{11pt}{\ClassError{sig-alternate}{The `11pt' option is
    not allowed}{sig-alternate now exists in 9pt and 10pt versions only}}
\DeclareOption{12pt}{\ClassError{sig-alternate}{The `12pt' option is
    not allowed}{sig-alternate now exists in 9pt and 10pt versions only}}

\ExecuteOptions{9pt}
\ProcessOptions
```

Thus, neither `11pt` nor `12pt` are supported. `9pt` and `10pt` are the only fontsize-related options, with `9pt` the default.

Do you have the option to use a different class file?

Comment: We're not required to use this specific template, but we *are* required to use ACM format standards. I don't know if that helps at all

Comment: @MrDuk - Can you figure out if any of the other ACM document classes lets you utilize a `12pt` font size.